# Maven install on macOS failure

Tags: macos, maven, macos-catalina

I've been trying to install maven on macOS Catalina, did all the the steps from downlaoding to reloading the .bash_profile after updating with necessary export statements, the thing is once i restart my terminal, maven is no longer known by the system.

```
    export M2_HOME=/Users/****/apache-maven-3.6.3
    export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

once I put this config, things go fine maven is recognised but once I restart my terminal session, mvn command is no longer recognised and I have to run the following command to make it work again

```
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

hope you guys have some answers, I'm really stuck here.

thanks so much

Comment: Have you tried to call maven with absolute path like `/Users/../apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn --version`?

Comment: not an answer to your specific question but the easiest way to install maven is with homebrew, just run  "brew install maven" on the other hand, have you tried setting your configuration on "~/.bashrc" ?

Comment: Do you have an error message from OS or terminal?

I suggest trying from the comment above.
If you run maven from an absolute path. It should be can execute. If not you should install a maven from homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already fix this but for who will search for this i think the problem was with Catalina new `"The default interactive shell is now zsh."`, so:

- if you use default `zsh` you need to update `$HOME/.profile`
- if you use `bash` you need to update `$HOME/.bash_profile`

with this:

```
export M2_HOME=YOUR_FOLDER_WHERE_MAVEN_IS/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```